# Vuex store: When i try to add new object to array cause error as "Duplicate keys detected: 'test1'. This may cause an update error. "

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

When I try to add an object to an array, it updates existing objects of the array and displays the error as: "Duplicate keys detected: 'test'. This may cause an update error". Can you please help me in resolving the issue.
Below is my code:

index.vue

```
methods: {
...mapActions({      
      saveItem: 'admin/saveItem'
    }),
    createItem() {      
      const saveItemFunc = this.saveItem            
      saveItemFunc({ "Test item", "category" })      
    },
}
actions.js
saveItem({ commit, dispatch, state }, payload) {
    commit('addItemToBeSaved', payload)
}

mutations.js
addItemToBeSaved: (state, { name, type }  ) => {        
  state.items.push(state.item)
  state.items[state.count].name = name
  state.items[state.count].type = type
  state.count = state.count + 1    
}

State.js
export default function() {
  return {        
    items: [],
    count: 0,
    item: {
      name: '',
      type: ''
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please, also upload your template section.

Comment: I guess you have a v-for loop in your vue file and no key defined.